# Android compatibility with Restlet/JSON/Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, restlet, jackson

I'm currently working on a webservice-client for Android. I'm using a Java client library which provides an abstraction for interaction with the service. The client library works on normal machines. However, when I use the classes in my Android project, some calls don't return a result on Android, the background-service stops working at the first of those commands. Wireshark shows a tcp exchange, the server gets the requests. There is no exceptions or anything. Something in the serialization/deserialization seams not to work. I'm using the newest version of Jackson libraries (1.5.3) and the restlet jar in the android edition. Is there any known problems with Jackson and Android? Which code and libraries are compatible with Android?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using [Gson](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for parsing JSON responses to POJO's. I find it easier and straightforward. The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android) may give you more options.

> Is there any known problems with
>   Jackson and Android?

As far as I know there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, later Jackson versions (including 1.5 and recently released 1.6) work just fine on Android: conveniently and efficiently.

For best compatibility 1.6.1 has some further improvements to reduce warnings during initialization (used to complain about missing javax.xml and Joda classes, not any more)