# how to send data from android to server

Tags: android, http, httpclient, http-post

I'm exploring to scan ssid and rssi from android and I'm able to do it, but now i have want send the data to the server, so i explore i found below code

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://101.34.45.45/rawData");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", "00-22-68-E8-EC-F1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", "2010-07-01 11:11:11"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        textView.setText(response.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

but now i'm having problem when add multi wifi data, the format should as below

http://101.34.45.45/rawData?data={"userId":"guest1","timestamp":"2010-07-01 08:58:23","wifi":[{"ssid":"guest","rssi":"40"},{"ssid":"guest1","rssi":"80"}]},

so how can done for the wifi parameter, can anyone help, I'm still trying for few varieties,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to switch to JSON for sending data to the server. [Google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is easiest to use to send and parse JSON.

```
{"userId":"guest1","timestamp":"2010-07-01 08:58:23","wifi":[{"ssid":"guest","rssi":"40"},{"ssid":"guest1","rssi":"80"}]}
```

You should use a JSON object having a JSON array as one of its items. The JSON array in turn contains another json object.

If you are using Google GSON, you should build a class hierarchy for the same. Heres how you should do the same.

```
Class data{

 String userId;
 String timestamp;
 Wifi wifi;
}

Class Wifi{

 String ssid;
 int rssi;
}
```

You can check [here](http://primalpop.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/parsing-json-using-gson-in-android/) for a sample code on a similar problem on parsing json in android.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android) may be useful too.

Comment: why introduce an additional third party dependency when the android SDK comes with a json library?

Comment: I found GSON easier to use for converting POJO's to json and vice versa than the inherent json library.

Comment: why cant we use POST rather than JSON.. bcos most of the time i will have a image being sent to the server.