# How to Send JSON String to server side in Android

Tags: android

I creats one apps in android.I have fetch data from server side useing json but i have proble how to send json string or jso to server

Comment: i have answered a similar question with some code example. please check [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950279/save-posts-to-rails-server-from-java-android-application-with-devise-authentica/8950868#8950868).

Answer (score 0):

You can create [JsonObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), put data in it and then convert it toString() for sending. How to do sending itself depends on your server.
Also, refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156975/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-server).

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you to use a fast parser if your data is large. I use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).
And you can find related code. With Jackson you can use Object Mapper for default map conversion

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
httppost.addData("points", getMapper().writeValueAsString(points));
InputStream instream = httpclient.execute(httppost).getEntity().getContent();
return getMapper().readValue(instream, HashMap.class);
```