# how to parse a json response in android

Tags: android, json

can some parse the json encode response from php into java arraylist.
My string is

```
[{"Link_Id":"811"},{"Link_Id":"1389"},{"Link_Id":"6190"}]
```

what I tried is

```
static JSONObject jObj = null;
JSONArray link_Ids = null;
ArrayList<Integer> ids;
jObj = new JSONObject(a);
link_Ids = jObj.getJSONArray("Link_Id");
for (int i = 0; i < link_Ids.length(); i++) {  // **line 2**
     JSONObject childJSONObject = link_Ids.getJSONObject(i);
     ids.add(childJSONObject.getString(i));
}
```

can some one please correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the string represents a json array so it should be like this:

```
link_Ids = new JSONArray(a);
for (int i = 0; i < link_Ids.length(); i++) {  
   JSONObject childJSONObject = link_Ids.getJSONObject(i);
   ids.add(childJSONObject.getString("Link_Id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson library for parsing JSON objects.It's Easy to use.Here is the Link for [gson parsing](http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/)

Here is the Stack Overflow [internal link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556230/using-gson-in-android-to-parse-a-complex-json-object)

For gson to work to need a .jar file.You can download the gson library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)