# Splitting a nested json to smaller jsons using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I want to get a part of list json from a whole nested one. I have a json that looks like following:

```
{
  "response": 200,
  "responseMsg": "Allright",
  "location": [
    {
      "stateId": 1,
      "stateName": "West Bengal",
      "district": [
        {
          "districtId": 15,
          "districtName": "abc",
          "village": [
            {
              "villageId": 121,
              "villageName": "ABC"
            },
            {
              "villageId": 90,
              "villageName": "XYZ"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "districtId": 11,
          "districtName": "xyz",
          "village": [
            {
              "villageId": 58,
              "villageName": "PQR"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have written the bean files as following :
Details.java:

```
public class Details {

    private int response = 0;
    private String responseMsg = null;
    private List<State> states = null;
public List<State> getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
```

State.java:

```
public class State {

    private int stateId = 0;

    private String stateName=null;

    private List<District> district;

    public List<District> getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }
```

Now, I want only the State json differently so that I can then use use it as List to populate the spinner in android. 
For parsing the json, I am using

```
Gson googleJson = builder.create();Details details = googleJson.fromJson(result, Details.class);               
List<State> stateList = details.getLocation();
```

But when i again convert this to json using `gson.toJson(stateList)` this gives:

```
[
  {
    "district": [
      {
        "village": [
          {
            "villageName": "Mekhliganj",
            "villageId": 57
          }
        ],
        "districtName": "Cooch Bihar",
        "districtId": 10
      }
],"stateName=West Bengal","stateId":1
}
}
```

But this is other way round as state name goes in end when i again convert it to json.
Also , this same json (stateList) gives null pointer exception when I again try to parse it as:

```
State stateObj = gson.fromJson(stateList,State.class);
```

What should be the correct way to do this ? i.e. get a part of json (list) from a whole using gson and parse that part ?

Comment: Confusing question I think, please ellaborate with proper way, you mentioned Json with "states" but in your response there is no tag named states. Please explain proper so can help you out,

Comment: @PratikDasa I meant location. I basically want a json that only has part of full json response i.e. a json with only list of states (and districts , villages as they are inside the state)

Comment: you must need to use GSON? And what is result vaiable? I mean string or array? @Prakruti

Comment: Need to get the json as string and then use result as arraylist later again for spinner adapter.

Comment: I think these questions links will help you : (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android  (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556230/using-gson-in-android-to-parse-a-complex-json-object

Comment: Have you got the answer? @Prakruti

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for you...

You are not passing the whole response in below function

try this steps to get whole response :

1) Store the data in String or any object class you are storing.

2)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
   String string = gson.toJson(response);
```

Note :  You are just parsing remaining response. You are not parsing the original response. Just recheck the response when you parse in above function by putting break point on it.

Comment: I have done the same thing to get the stae part of list as json. The problem is , I am not able to parse this json in to State Object. I want to parse only the sub part of response. It directly gives null exception when i do  State stateObj = gson.fromJson(stateList,State.class);

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Details {

    private int response = 0;
    private String responseMsg = null;
    private Location location = null;

    //add getter and setter

}

public class Location{
    private List<State>stateList;

//add getter and setter

}
```

Finally

```
public class State {

    private int stateId = 0;
    private String stateName=null;
    private List<District> district;

    //add getter and setter
}
```