# android how to get data from json having array within array

Tags: android, json

I have an application where i want to fetch data from local server.
like

```
{
    "restarutant":{
    "name":"Hotel Raja",
    "photo":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Mzt4u.jpg",
    "address":"93, 2ndc ross, GDP etx.",
    "area":"Vylaikaval",
    "city":"Bangalore",
    "location":["13.005621","77.577531"],
    "phone":["9986377561","08023467969"],
    "rating":"4",
    "cuisines":["Chinese","Korean"],
    "attributes":["smoking","parking","delivery"]
    }
}
```

means array within an array
please anybody tell me how i retrieve each data from this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        String str_json = "your json string from query";

    try {
        JSONObject topobj = new JSONObject(str_json);
        JSONObject innerobj = topobj.getJSONObject("restarutant");

        String name = innerobj.getString("name");
        String photo = innerobj.getString("photo");
        JSONArray cuisines = innerobj.getJSONArray("cuisines");
        //etc etc...

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the manual example using the [Tokenizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) or use your own implementation.

Also read this post: 
[Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android) answers your question.

Comment: ya but i want to know how to retrieve in my abdroid activity page. please give me that answer