# How do i parse json object and json array in android?

Tags: android, json

I am developing an app using json api and want to implement following format api into my app. How do i implement this in my project using android studio 2.3?

```
{
    "getdetailsasanas": [
        {
            "asanaid": 1,
            "asananame": "Half easy gas release pose",
            "duration": 1,
            "imageurl": "http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/images/half-easy-gas-release-pose.jpg",
            "imageversion": 2,
            "audiourl": "http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/audio/half-easy-gas-release-pose.mp3",
            "audioversion": 1,
            "videourl": "NULL",
            "videoversion": 0,
            "StepsForAsana": [
                {
                    "stepnumber": 1,
                    "stepdesc": "Step 1",
                    "stepimg": "http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/images/asana-step/half-easy-gas-release-pose-step1.jpg",
                    "stepimgeversion": 0,
                    "imgethumbversion": 1,
                    "imgethumburl": "http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/images/asana-step/half-easy-gas-release-pose-step1-tb.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "stepnumber": 2,
                    "stepdesc": "Step 2",
                    "stepimg": "http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/images/asana-step/half-easy-gas-release-pose-step2.jpg",
                    "stepimgeversion": 0,
                    "imgethumbversion": 1,
                    "imgethumburl": "http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/images/asana-step/half-easy-gas-release-pose-step2-tb.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show your work .

Comment: Did you try googling it? It would surprise me if you would be the first person in the world that is going to parse JSON on an Android platform

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: And see this same as your response structure [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6773474/1512199)

Comment: plz suggest me how do i implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONObject its default supplied with android SDK:

```
String json = "some JSON";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Than you can use methods like

```
getBoolean(String key)
getDouble(String key)
```

etc

Or you can use google gson library which is in my opinion better, but you will need to include it as dependency in gradle.

[There is github for the Gson.](https://github.com/google/gson)

[There is Gson API](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson library . Best way to parse the responses.Your can user GsonFormat plugin to generate the model for response.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [gson](https://github.com/google/gson). It's a easy serializer for json.

Answer (score 0):

It's my pleasure to answer your question.
You can do like this.

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("getdetailsasanas");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            String asanaid = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("asanaid");
            String asananame = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("asananame");
            String duration = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("duration");
            String imageurl = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imageurl");
            String imageversion = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imageversion");
            String videourl = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("videourl");
            String videoversion = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("videoversion");
            JSONArray StepsForAsanaArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("StepsForAsana");
            for (int j = 0; j < StepsForAsanaArray.length(); j++) {
                String stepnumber = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("stepnumber");
                String stepdesc = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("stepdesc");
                String stepimg = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("stepimg");
                String stepimgeversion = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("stepimgeversion");
                String imgethumbversion = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("imgethumbversion");
                String imgethumburl = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("imgethumburl");
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you must decrease your implementation

Comment: sure.I got it.But I don't know what he needs.

Comment: But I think that `Gson` or `Fastjson` will be better

Comment: how do i show result of above string to text

Comment: @KeLiuyue is for newbie programers

Comment: im new in proramming so i quite confuse to show result

Comment: @Rohi check my post

Comment: yes i check this but how do i show result of above string format to textfields?

Answer (score 0):

Use like with this code:

```
JSONArray getdetailsasanas = new JSONArray(stringData);
for (int p = 0; p < getdetailsasanas.length(); p++) {
    try {
        JSONObject data = getdetailsasanas.getJSONObject(p);
        JSONObject asanaid    = data.getJSONObject("asanaid");
        JSONObject stepnumber = data.getJSONObject("stepnumber");
        JSONObject stepnumber = data.getJSONObject("stepnumber");


        //get data from objetcs
        String asananame = asanaid.getString("asananame");
        int duration = asanaid.getInt("duration");
        String imageurl = asanaid.getString("imageurl");


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rohi my post updated