# How to take data from json object...?

Tags: android, json

I just start working with JSON data.

```
[[[170, "kod", 148, 13, "2011-07-11T03:33:57Z", 11.68, 10.0, 1310373205707,     "2939393939"]], [{"announcement": {"post_by": null, "created_at": "2010-09-04T09:59:12Z", "announcement_category": null, "updated_at": "2010-09-04T09:59:12Z", "valid_till": "2010-09-04T09:59:00Z", "priority": null, "id": 3, "condtions": "", "message": "hello"}}]]
```

I want to get:

```
[170, "kod", 148, 13, "2011-07-11T03:33:57Z", 11.68, 10.0, 1310373205707, "0976741509"]
```

and

```
[{"announcement": {"post_by": null, "created_at": "2010-09-04T09:59:12Z", "announcement_category": null, "updated_at": "2010-09-04T09:59:12Z", "valid_till": "2010-09-04T09:59:00Z", "priority": null, "id": 3, "condtions": "", "message": "hello"}}]
```

in string

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Existing libraries for parsing JSON for Android/Java**

There's an excellent answer to this posted here:

- [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

> I am surprised these have not been mentioned: but instead of using
>   bare-bones rather manual process with json.org's little package, GSon
>   and Jackson are much more convenient to use. So:
>
> - [GSON](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)
> - [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)
>
> So you can actually bind to your own POJOs, not some half-assed tree
>   nodes or Lists and Maps. (and at least Jackson allows binding to such
>   things too (perhaps GSON as well, not sure), JsonNode, Map, List, if
>   you really want these instead of 'real' objects)