# JSON PARSING IN ANDROID?

Tags: android, json

I need to parse Json in Android, as a newbie in Json as well as in Android I am unable to do so here is the json String:

```
[
    {
        "chapter": "1. General",
        "lessons": [
            {
                "lesson": "1.1 "
            },
            {
                "lesson": "1.2"
            },
            {
                "lesson": "1.3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "chapter": "2.emergencies"
    }
]
```

Here I just want to get the lessons array data. So any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android

Comment: put json string here => http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ click view ... you will see tree ... [] means array, {} means object/dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject chapObject = jObject.getJSONObject("chapter");
Log.d("Chapt", chapObject.getString("chapter"));
JSONArray lessonArray = popupObject.getJSONArray("lessons");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
Log.d("Name", lessonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lesson").toString());

Log.d("Value", lessonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("onclick").toString());   
}      
JSONObject chap2Object = jObject.getJSONObject("chapter");
Log.d("Chapt2", chapObject.getString("chapter"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject and/or JSONArray. They can be created directly from strings, eg:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android includes a JSON parser: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

```
String json = "{ ... }";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("lessions");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    String lession = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("lession");
}
```