# Which book is the best for learning web-services in Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am trying to learn how to develop web applications for Android platform, I was told that we use SOAP, JSON and HTML5 for getting and setting data using XML, now the problem is when I Google Android Web services I get very few good links that really help in understanding a concept and moreover books out in the market don't quite focus on web services, can you experienced developers please suggest me an excellent book to get started as well as go pro in web services particularly for Android platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished up an app that uses REST JSON. I did not find any one book that had all the information. The Manning Android in Action covers some of the web call structure (but they use the defunct Google Base in the example) - see the resturant example, I think it was in Chapter 3. I was able to build on this using examples on the web to get it working. I'll see if I can't find some of those links.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/

Comment: Also see this SE question - pretty sure that will get you there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android

Comment: Also it's worth noting that SOAP/XML and JSON are usually mutually exclusive technologies. Or at least some web services will return your choice of SOAP/XML or JSON, but I have never seen JSON data encoded in XML. Not saying it might not exist - it's just not the "normal" was to use JSON - to the extent there can be such a thing. :-)

Comment: Thank you mate that was generous:), it is a shame that good books dont teach you how to do that. I will be grateful if you provide me those links if you can.

Comment: yeah ive seen it:) thanks again:)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, REST/JSON is the way to go.

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

Android REST: use HttpClient. [Example](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/).

Android JSON: use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: First two links are broken