# How to parse this JSON object

Tags: android, json

This is the json response from my server . How can i parse it and store it in HashMap? Please help me.

```
 {'records':
     [{
        'number':165, 
        'description': 'abcd'
      },
      {
         'number':166, 
         'description': 'ab'
      },
      {
         'number':167, 
         'description': 'abc'
      }]
  }
```

Comment: The programming language you're using may provide a JSON parser as standard library functionality, but since you're not disclosing which language you're using, it's hard to help you.

Comment: 17 questions asked and not a single answer accepted? Really?? Please fix this before asking more questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im new in android but maybe you can do something like this:

```
JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray JsonArray_ = JsonObject .getJSONArray("records");

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
JSONObject record= JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(i);    
parsedObject.number = record.getString("number"); //its the same for all fields        
map.add(parsedObject);
}
```

I done something like that for my own JSON parser. hope this helps. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the gson library, which makes it very easy indeed to parse JSON into an object representing the data. So you could create a Record object, with public member variables for number, description, and then use gson to parse the JSON into an object array.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Add the .jar to your libs folder and then use it like this:

```
Record[] records = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString,Record[].class)
int number = record[0].number;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `org.json` package is included in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Use is simple:

```
JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(String json_string);
```

Each property can then be accessed as a Java property, e.g. `json_object.property`. It will throw a `JSONException` if the parsing fails for some reason (i.e., invalid JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library, you can find full tutorial on [softwarepassion.com](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/)