# android - how to handle ws response

Tags: android, json

In my application i am getting the following response from the web response. what it means? can anybody help me.

```
ws:response

08-29 13:19:32.604: INFO/System.out(478): {"status":"FAILED","response":null,
"reason":"Input string was not in a correct format."}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON string. You can decode it using the classes JSONObject, JSONArray, ...

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a JSON-response. Use built-in in Android sdk org.json library or some 3rd party ones (see [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android))

to parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON error message. I've got a good [manual](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) for you to learn how to handle it.