# Using Perl data on server to display on Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application. I am calling a Perl file on a server. This Perl file has different print statements.

I want to make the collective text available to a variable in android Java file of mine.

I have tried this :

```
URL url= new URL("http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/myfile.pl?var=97320");
```

here goes my request to the server file. But how can i get the data from the Perl file available there?

Comment: By "PERL" do you mean the script is in the programming language Perl?

Comment: Yes... The script is in PERL language. Sorry for being Ambiguous if...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your perl service:

```
use CGI qw(param header);
use JSON;

my $var = param('var');

my $json = &fetch_return_data($var);

print header('application/json');

print to_json($json); # or encode_json($json) for utf-8
```

to return data as a JSON object. Then use one of many JSON libraries for Java to read the data. For instance http://json.org/java/:

```
Integer var = 97320;
InputStream inputStream = new URL("http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/myfile.pl?var=" + var).openStream();
try {
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  // Or this if you returned utf-8 from your service
  //BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readAll(bufferedReader));
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: There is actually a JSON library included with the Android libraries, but it is not the easiest to use: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android