# How to filter an implicit intent in android.?

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the following code to call google map and retrieve data using implicit intent.

```
Intent searchAddress = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("geo:0,0?q=" + location));
startActivity(searchAddress);**
```

I want some information about hospitals instead of showing all the data in Google Maps.

Is this possible to specify the location and place in implicit intent ACTION VIEW..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps/Google Places API directly, without calling Intents.

All yo need is:

- Obtain [Google Maps API key](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
- Prepare an URL with the query parameters like location and what you're looking for (See the [reference here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchJSON)).
- Fetch the response from the URL (there are lot of tutorials how to download sth on Android)
- Parse the response, for example [using JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android).

Comment: I did that..! Thanks for your response..!