# How do I parse JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json, parsing

How do I parse a JSON feed in Android?

Comment: Dont know about Android, but under normal Java I use this: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ EDIT: Does work under android:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: there is a json parser embedded in the sdk. see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840873/643350

Comment: You can have look at below link where you get data using retrofit. http://www.tatnorix.in/how-to-get-json-data-using-get-retrofit-in-android/

Comment: You can use gson in android too: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: You can use the org.json library for this. While it is not the best library for more complex processes, it is great for simply parsing JSON. [This short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IGl4Tf2VVI) demonstrates this.

Comment: In Android, there are many good libraries been introduced which are light-weighted and easy to use. Try using Moshi library. https://github.com/square/moshi

Answer (score 267):

Android has all the tools you need to parse json built-in. Example follows, no need for GSON or anything like that.

**Get your JSON:**

Assume you have a json string

```
String result = "{\"someKey\":\"someValue\"}";
```

**Create a [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html):**

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

If your json string is an array, e.g.:

```
String result = "[{\"someKey\":\"someValue\"}]"
```

then you should use `JSONArray` as demonstrated below and not `JSONObject`

**To get a specific string**

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("STRINGNAME");
```

**To get a specific boolean**

```
boolean aJsonBoolean = jObject.getBoolean("BOOLEANNAME");
```

**To get a specific integer**

```
int aJsonInteger = jObject.getInt("INTEGERNAME");
```

**To get a specific long**

```
long aJsonLong = jObject.getLong("LONGNAME");
```

**To get a specific double**

```
double aJsonDouble = jObject.getDouble("DOUBLENAME");
```

**To get a specific [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html):**

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("ARRAYNAME");
```

**To get the items from the array**

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Pulling items from the array
        String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("STRINGNAMEinTHEarray");
        String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("anotherSTRINGNAMEINtheARRAY");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Oops
    }
}
```

Comment: There also could be a case when you receive an JSONArray and if you try to JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result) - you'll get an exeption about parsing. In such case JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result) would work.

Answer (score 25):

1. Writing JSON Parser Class

   ```
   public class JSONParser {

       static InputStream is = null;
       static JSONObject jObj = null;
       static String json = "";

       // constructor
       public JSONParser() {}

       public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

           // Making HTTP request
           try {
               // defaultHttpClient
               DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               is = httpEntity.getContent();

           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           try {
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String line = null;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   sb.append(line + "\n");
               }
               is.close();
               json = sb.toString();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
           }

           // try parse the string to a JSON object
           try {
               jObj = new JSONObject(json);
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
           }

           // return JSON String
           return jObj;

       }
   }
   ```
2. Parsing JSON Data
   Once you created parser class next thing is to know how to use that class. Below i am explaining how to parse the json (taken in this example) using the parser class.

   2.1. Store all these node names in variables: In the contacts json we have items like name, email, address, gender and phone numbers. So first thing is to store all these node names in variables. Open your main activity class and declare store all node names in static variables.

   ```
   // url to make request
   private static String url = "http://api.9android.net/contacts";

   // JSON Node names
   private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
   private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
   private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
   private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
   private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
   private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
   private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
   private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
   private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
   private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

   // contacts JSONArray
   JSONArray contacts = null;
   ```

   2.2. Use parser class to get `JSONObject` and looping through each json item. Below i am creating an instance of `JSONParser` class and using for loop i am looping through each json item and finally storing each json data in variable.

   ```
   // Creating JSON Parser instance
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

   // getting JSON string from URL
   JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

       try {
       // Getting Array of Contacts
       contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

       // looping through All Contacts
       for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
           JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

           // Storing each json item in variable
           String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
           String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
           String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
           String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
           String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

           // Phone number is agin JSON Object
           JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
           String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
           String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
           String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

       }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: This answer somewhat skips over downloading the JSON off of the main thread

Answer (score 16):

I've coded up a simple example for you and annotated the source. The example shows how to grab live json and parse into a `JSONObject` for detail extraction:

```
try{
    // Create a new HTTP Client
    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Setup the get request
    HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://example.json");

    // Execute the request in the client
    HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
    // Grab the response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String json = reader.readLine();

    // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

} catch(Exception e){
    // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Once you have your `JSONObject` refer to the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for details on how to extract the data you require.

Comment: Hi i have put this in but getting errors i have imported everything but still getting problems

Comment: You will need to wrap the code block above in a try-catch, I've edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: if the file retrieved has newline characters, the `readLine()` fails.