# JSON parsing with android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Can anyone please point me to a tutorial or something for parsing JSON strings in android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android

Comment: [Have a look at this magician](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+json+parsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some tutorials

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/07/another-example-to-parse-json.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not a tutorial, but it will be useful four you: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: please post this as a comment. You should add code snippets alongside such a link if you want to proceed so anyway

Comment: GSON saves us so much time and effort, just a little fiddly with arrays occasioanly

Comment: ladiesMan217, got it, next time I will post comment

Comment: Why does this need to be a comment? There are *lots* of other answers where there is a link to a lib. The GSON site has tutorials and guides with code in, therefore why reinvent the wheel? I am sure a user can click the provided link.

Comment: @GrahamSmith See [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for various reasons. I personally don't like these answers because links can be dead; if the only, accepted answer is a link, the question becomes completely useless for search engine users. If it's a comment, others are still encouraged to give a "proper" answer because the question is not done.

Comment: I looked through previous answers I have given and I have included sample code in most of them. Thanks for the meta link was quite informative. When i get edit privileges I shall alter any posts of mine that reference just a link to help the community now I know :)