# get coordinates from JSON from google maps

Tags: android, json

I'm getting my position from an address, I use this [website](http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=address%20city%20country):

I get JSON data, but I dont know how to read it in my Android app.

```
{
  "name": "plaza mayor 1 madrid España",

  "Status": {

    "code": 200,

    "request": "geocode"

  },

  "Placemark": [ {

    "id": "p1",

    "address": "Plaza Mayor, 1, 28012 Madrid, España",

    "AddressDetails": {

   "Accuracy" : 8,

   "Country" : {

      "AdministrativeArea" : {

         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "Comunidad de Madrid",

         "SubAdministrativeArea" : {

            "Locality" : {

               "LocalityName" : "Madrid",

               "PostalCode" : {

                  "PostalCodeNumber" : "28012"

               },

               "Thoroughfare" : {

                  "ThoroughfareName" : "Plaza Mayor, 1"

               }

            },

            "SubAdministrativeAreaName" : "Madrid"

         }

      },

      "CountryName" : "España",

      "CountryNameCode" : "ES"

   }

},

    "ExtendedData": {

      "LatLonBox": {

        "north": 40.4164186,

        "south": 40.4137207,

        "east": -3.7053139,

        "west": -3.7080118

      }

    },

    "Point": {

      "coordinates": [ -3.7066379, 40.4150359, 0 ]

    }

  } ]

}
```

How can I read the "coordinates" tag?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parse it, to begin with, then access the various elements :

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseAsString);
JSONObject point = response.getJSONArray("Placemark").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("Point");

double lat = point.getJSONArray("coordinates").getDouble(0);
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some sort of framwork to handle your Json data, here's a good aexample. Then you can handle your data as a regular object.

[Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Good luck!