# parse string array from JSON

Tags: java, json

i have this JSON object:

```
{"error":null,
 "result":[{"id":"1234567890",
            "count":1,
            "recipients":
            ["u3848",
               "u8958",
               "u7477474"
            ],
            "dateCreated":"2012-06-13T09:13:45.989Z"
           }]
 }
```

and I'm trying to find a way to correctly parse the `recipients` array into a `String[]` object.

is there an easy way to do this?

**EDIT:**

found this answer that has all the things needed for result: [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Comment: Which Json(Java) library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the `org.json.JSONObject` library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the way to do what I wanted was this:

```
JSONArray temp = jsonObject.getJSONArray("name");
int length = temp.length();
if (length > 0) {
    String [] recipients = new String [length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        recipients[i] = temp.getString(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that "name" attribute coming from? You don't have that anywhere in your original post.

Comment: the `name` attribute needs to be predefined since JSON is a key/value store.

Comment: Right. (I was wondering because you replied to your own question, where the key was not there.) Should be "recipients" instead of "name" therefore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use xstream with json serializer. Take a look [this link](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest my favorite library [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html) to handle JSON stuffs.

You can use [JSONArray](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html) to convert to `Object[]`, although it's not `String[]`, you can still use it because every `Object` has `toString()` method.

```
String sYourJsonString = "['u3848', 'u8958', 'u7477474']";
Object[] arrayReceipients = JSONArray.toArray (JSONArray.fromObject(sYourJsonString));
System.out.println (arrayReceipients [0]); // u3848
```