# List from encoded string

Tags: java, json

I have a string like :

```
"\"[\"a\",\"b\", \"c\"]\""
```

How to convert this to a list of strings

Could you suggest me a nice way of doing it in Java?

Comment: have you tried anything yet? where is the problem?

Comment: Does this string contain JSON?

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012044/parse-string-array-from-json - okay, I guess this question's more unclear than anything.

Comment: Oh, and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297816/stripslashes-in-android-java, possibly.  Though that question doesn't appear to have a correct answer...

Comment: Do you have question on Java? or JASON??

Comment: JAVA and JSON both are different!!

Answer (score 1):

`str.contains("c")` does this job. However did not you think to consult String class documentation first?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
if (str.contains("\"c\""))
```