# Parsing an array of json in android

Tags: android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

```
     {
       "appstore_information":{
          "allow_jail_broken_devices":true,
          "can_edit_text":true,
          "disabled_device_features":[
             2,
             7,
             8
          ],
          "enable_document_sharing":true,
          "enable_icloud":true,
          "enable_internal_app":true,
          "enable_itunes":true,
          "enable_local_download":false,
          "enable_screen_capture":true,
          "idle_time_out":7,
          "last_modified_date":"9\/28\/2012 1:01:17 PM",
          "locations":[
             {
                "latitude":"12.824261",
                "location":"Siruseri SEZ",
                "longitude":"80.219969",
                "radius_in_miles":6
             },
             {
                "latitude":"13.02329",
                "location":"DLF",
                "longitude":"80.17509",
                "radius_in_miles":7
             }
          ],
          "offline_access_type":1,
          "profile_id":1,
          "profile_name":"Profile",
          "require_ad_authentication":true,
          "use_offline_access":false
       },
       "display_message":"Profile is available in information.",
       "

message_status":"Success."
}
```

Dis is my json response what is the approach to parse locations and store the individual data in an array in android?

Comment: this is not in josnArray format this is in jsonObject format. keep the above code between [];

Answer (score 0):

First try with [This Json Parsing Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). It give you explanation how to parse your json and display response.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android) answer. There are thousands of topics about json parsing in internet

Answer (score 0):

What about using json parser ( android provides one,  but there are better solutions like:
https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer )

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. Mainly use JSONObject Class and JSONArray class from the android SDK