# Accessing json contents in android

Tags: android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

I have a `JSON` result in the following format which `JSON Lint` shows this as a `Valid Response`.

My question is: how do I accesss the content of "reportId0" value "164", "reportId1" value `157`,`reportId2 value 165`, etc are all dynamic values?

My sample code for accessing value of `properties`.How to get Value `reportid` And add allvalue in `Arraylist`?

```
"properties": {    
    "link": "",
    "approvalsReportCount": 3,
    "reportName0": "srcapprovals",
    "reportId0": 164,
    "reportName1": "Approvals",
    "reportId1": 157,
    "requests_report_id": "163",
    "requests_report_name": "EG approvals",
    "reportName2": "fulfillment",
    "reportId2": 165
}
```

Comment: Try this - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @KristopherMicinski read OP's question fully. He is having problem of parsing dynamic keys.

Comment: Use gson parsing for parsing.It will be more easy for you.Here is the Link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: @PareshMayani read it fully before voting to close.

Comment: @PareshMayani thanks for your credit. And now you can continue with your work. Still, if you think you are good at editing why don't you volunteer, instead criticizing others and their efforts.

Comment: @AndroSelva i did editing earlier so whats wrong with that? Do you work.

Comment: Hi @Pankit please post your original json string again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try This!!

```
try {
               JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
               JSONObject jsonResultArray = jObj.getJSONObject("results");
               Log.v("log_tag","json result Array :   "+ jsonResultArray);

               JSONObject pro_object = jsonResultArray.getJSONObject("properties");

               Iterator keys = pro_object.keys();

                 while(keys.hasNext()) {
                      // loop to get the dynamic key
                      String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
                      String value = pro_object.getString(currentDynamicKey);
                      approvaldto_Key = new All_Approval_Key_dto();

                      String upToEightCharacters = currentDynamicKey.substring(0, Math.min(currentDynamicKey.length(), 8));

                      if(upToEightCharacters.startsWith("reportId"))
                      {

                          approvaldto_Key.requestId = pro_object.getString(currentDynamicKey);
                          fetchrecursUserData.add(approvaldto_Key);
                      }

                  }

              }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            }

          return  fetchrecursUserData;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way i found it to get ReportId value.

Below is My code

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject jsonResultArray = jObj.getJSONObject("results");
            JSONObject pro_object = jsonResultArray.getJSONObject("properties");
            Iterator keys = pro_object.keys();
           while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
                String value = pro_object.getString(currentDynamicKey);
                String upToEightCharacters = currentDynamicKey.substring(0, Math.min(currentDynamicKey.length(), 8));

                if(upToEightCharacters.startsWith("reportId"))
                {

                    Log.v("key"," new report ID key  " + currentDynamicKey);
                    Log.v("key"," new report ID key  " + pro_object.getString(currentDynamicKey) );

                }
              }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
public ArrayList<String> getReportIds() {
    boolean isContinue = true;
    JSONObject json;
    String tag = "reportId";
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<String> repIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject prop = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject("<your json string>");
        prop = json.getJSONObject("properties");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isContinue) {
        String repId = "";
        try {
            repId = prop.getString(tag + i);
            repIdList.add(repId);
            i++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            isContinue = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return repIdList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
String serial= jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getString("serialNumber");
```

or

```
JSONObject json;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
    String accessToken = json.getString("access_token");
    return accessToken;
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("Podcast", "There was an error", e);
}
```