# How to make parsing faster for large and complex JSON?

Tags: android, json

I want to parse a large JSON. How can I make it faster? Now it takes a lot of time. Please help me.

Comment: Use a library that has been tested and optimized for that already. Why are you writing your own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can use some wrappers like http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ it is optimised to handle large data from json and easy to use.

Also you can give it try to http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ for better performance.

Following are the others.

- Android built-in: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html
- JSON.simple: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/
- Jackson: http://jackson.codehaus.org/
- Gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

You can check comparison article [over here](http://martinadamek.com/2011/01/31/comparison-of-json-parsers-performance-on-android/).

Answer (score 0):

According to some [benchmarks](http://martinadamek.com/2011/02/04/json-parsers-performance-on-android-with-warmup-and-multiple-iterations/) Jackson is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Use jackson JSON processor http://jackson.codehaus.org/
Most of the time people end up parsing the whole JSON and ignoring most of the data. This makes the process slow. If you are going to discard a lot of data, parsing in SAX mode is much faster, since you can stop parsing as soon as you have found all the required data.