# Json data from php server not working.

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am uplodaing data in MYSQL data base and at the same time I want to retrieve one of the attribute which I have inserted, for the satisfaction of my successful upload. when I press the button for first time then, it only upload the data to the server, and return nothing. Again when I hit the button then it does both the processs(insertion and retrieving data), so I can't return value at a first time in form of json object.

This is my php code `engrdatainsert.php`

```
 <?php  
$sqlCon=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("PeopleData");
 //Retrieve the data from the Android Post done by and Engr...
 $adp_no = $_REQUEST['adp_no'];
 $building_no = $_POST['building_no'];
 $contractor_name = $_POST['contractor_name'];
 $officer_name = $_POST['officer_name'];
  $area = $_POST['area'];
```

-------------------insert the received value from an Android----------||

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO engrdata (adp_no, building_no,area,contractor_name,officer_name)     VALUES('$adp_no', '$building_no', '$are',  '$contractor_name', '$officer_name')";
```

//--------Now check out the transaction status of the Inserted data---------||

```
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT adp_no FROM engrdata WHERE adp_no='$adp_no'");
   while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));//conveting into json array
   mysql_close();
     ?>
```

**My Android code**

```
 public void insertdata()
   {
 InputStream is=null;
 String result=null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("adp_no",adp));//"34")); 
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("building_no",bldng));//"72"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",myarea));//"72"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contractor_name",cntrct));//"72"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("officer_name",ofcr));//"72"));
    //http post
       try{
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new   HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/androidconnection/engrdatainsert.php"); 
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }   
 //convert the input strem into a string value
    try
      {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());   }
    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           Toast.makeText(this, "data is "+json_data.getString("adp_no")+"\n",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           String return_val = json_data.getString("adp_no");
           if(return_val!=null)
           {
             Intent offff=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
              offff.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
              offff.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              //startActivity(offff);
           }
        }
    }
    //}
    catch(JSONException e)
    {      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());        }
   // return returnString;//*/
    }
```

Comment: See this link [JSON IN ANDROID][1]
 May you will find your solution here in this link

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you PHP code, you are not executing the INSERT query.  You need to do something like this:

-------------------insert the received value from an Android----------||

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO engrdata (adp_no, building_no,area,contractor_name,officer_name)     VALUES('$adp_no', '$building_no', '$are',  '$contractor_name', '$officer_name')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

//--------Now check out the transaction status of the Inserted data---------||

Notice the line I added, which actually executes the query.

Now of course you should upgrade your code to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [mysqlPDO](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php) since the PHP mysql package is not supported anymore.

Comment: ! would my this code be not able to work on remote host,for uploading and retrieving data,

Comment: I'm sorry I can't quite understand your comment here.

Comment: i meant that i am developing an apps where i will upload some data to server from phone, but currently i am working this practice on localhost, if i will used a remote host, like any website, where i have stored my Data Base, then would the above code will work in that case

Comment: that's right, except you will need to change this part: `$sqlCon=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");` since you will no longer be accessing the server at localhost.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JSON in android for server purposes. like if you want to send data and retrieve a response from the server, then You have to use the JSON in accurate manner which have been defined in this link [Json in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)