# How do I separate out a JSON object embedded within a string for Android?

Tags: android, json, ksoap2

I am consuming a string containing JSON, which is passed by an ASP web service to Android. The string that I receive in my Android app is as follows:

```
GetCustomerListResponse{GetCustomerListResult=[{"VehicleID":"KL-9876","VehicleType":"Nissan","VehicleOwner":"Sanjiva"}]; }
```

**Say I want to get the vehicle type from the JSON string, how do i do that?**

My complete **Android code** is as follows:

```
package com.example.objectpass;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView resultA;
    Spinner spinnerC;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] toSpinnerSum;
        toSpinnerSum = new String[9];

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinnerC = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        resultA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCustomerList";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetCustomerList";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.100/WebService4/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

            resultA.setText(response.toString());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse current Json String as:

```
 //Convert String to JsonArray
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());

 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    // get json object from json Array
  JSONObject jsonobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

  //get VehicleType from jsonObject
   String str_VehicleType=jsonobj.getString("VehicleType");

  //get VehicleOwner from jsonObject
   String str_VehicleOwner=jsonobj.getString("VehicleOwner");

 }
```

and for more info how we parse an josn string in android see

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/

Comment: Hey i made the change as follows:
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
       // get json object from json Array
     JSONObject jsonobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

     //get VehicleType from jsonObject
      String str_VehicleType=jsonobj.getString("VehicleType");

     //get VehicleOwner from jsonObject
      String str_VehicleOwner=jsonobj.getString("VehicleOwner");
     
      resultA.setText(str_VehicleType);

but nothing is displayed in the resultA text view... any idea?

Comment: @najjaseven : you will need to put some log and check in log you are getting value from json or not in str_VehicleType variable.

Comment: @najjaseven : what string you are getting in response.toString() ?

Comment: GetCustomerListResponse{GetCustomerListResult=[{"VehicleID":"KL-9876","VehicleType":"Nissan","VehicleOwner":"Sanjiva"}]; }

when i insert the json code im not getting anything displayed!

Comment: @najjaseven : friend this string is not an valid json string .first extract json string from response then pass it in my code

Comment: @najjaseven : use  `String tempstr=response.toString().replace("GetCustomerListResponse{GetCustomerListResult=",""); tempstr=tempstr.replace("}]; }","}]");` to replace other part and then pass tempstr to jsonArray

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class. Tutorial can be found [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/). Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
final int jsonBeginIdx = response.firstIndexOf("=");
final int jsonEndIdx = response.lastIndexOf(";");

if(jsonBeginIdx > 0 && jsonEndIdx > jsonBeginIdx) {
    final String jsn = response.substring(jsonBeginIdx + 1, jsonEndIdx);
    final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
} else {
    // deal with malformed response here
}
```