# How Do I Build A JSON Object Like This In Java (android)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I need to build a JSONObject that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "login": {
        "email": "blah@blah.com",
        "password": "password"
    }
}
```

I understand that I'm supposed to use `jsonObject.put("key", "value)`, but how to I get the parent "login" node with nested keys / values?

Will I have an easier time building objects like this with Gson? Some of them are pretty complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In pure "android-java", this would look like that:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("email", "blah@blah.com");
data.put("password", "password");

JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
login.put("login", data);
```

Then you'll have your JSON object.

A good idea is to read some articles about JSON and Android:

1. [JSONObject javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)
2. [Vogella's article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)
3. [stackoverflow.com questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Comment: cool thanks. yeah, i read the top two articles :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject();

        innerObj.put("email","blah@blah.com");
        innerObj.put("password","password");

        mainObj.put("login", innerObj);

        System.out.println("JSON : "  +mainObj);
```