# (Android) JSON POST request and recive data

Tags: android, json

Hey I'm a student who has to create an android app where you send a message and the server responds. This is what they send me:

```
$request = curl_init('URL');

curl_setopt_array($request, array(

CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(‘Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8’),
CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'mail@email.com:password',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array('message' => 'Hey')),
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, // do not verify certificate for https
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, // return response as string instead of outputting it
));
$response = curl_exec($request);
```

- It has to send a POST request
- Username and password has to be in the header
- body has to have JSON, example { “message”: “Hey” }
- It receives JSON which contains the attributes `message` and `action`

I have looked everywhere and i couldn't find a good example also this is the first time I'm doing anything like this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That looks like PHP code not android code? Do you want to convert PHP code to android? What have you done?

Comment: Yes it is. He has given me this example and i can't figure it out how to connect to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Comment: Have a look at Retrofit here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

It gives you the tool to make a POST request with a JSON as body. Read the documentation, it's fairly easy to use.