# how to access to data from JSON object in Android?

Tags: android, json

My JSONObject:

```
JSONObject callback = {"message": "message here", "response": "response here"}
```

I want get the **response here**  from **json's respone** string.
I've tried the following:

```
JSONObject response = callback.getJSONObject("response");
String message = next.getString("response");
```

I get the errot like **String and JSONObjet conversion problems**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Comment: I don't agree, I'm not looking to use a third party library. I just want to get access to that one variable the way I am doing it with JSONObject.

Comment: "response" holds a JSONObject or String?

Comment: @sark9012 Well, the answers are not only about 3rd party libraries, there are also a lot of tutorials and other links that show the proper use of methods on `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
JSONObject callback = {"message": "message here", "response": "response here"}

String response = callback.getString("response");
String message = callback.getString("message");
```

Answer (score 1):

JSONObject callback = {"message": "message here", "response": "response here"}

you need to access response value  like below code

```
String response = callback.getString("response");
```