# Get JSON Response in android?

Tags: android, json

I want to this kind of `Json Parsing` which is provide in below and fetch the data from `Json Parsing Data`. But it give me `NullPointer Exception` whenever Execute my code(Do in Background Process) Which is provided in below. How to solve this problem? How to get the `JSON Response` from this below URL?

**data = {"2015-03-06":[{"date":"2015-03-06","sign":"0"}]};**

My Code is,

```
 @Override
     urlGetData= "view-source:XXXXXXXX?date=YYYY-MM-DD&sign=2XXXX";
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                        jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlGetData);
                        try {


                            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("YYYY-MM-DD");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                // Retrive JSON Objects

                                strRating = String.valueOf(jsonobject
                                        .getString("rating"));
                                dataList.add(map);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
```

But it gives me `Null Pointer Exception` on `jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("YYYY-MM-DD")`.

How can get theresponse of  data = `{"2015-03-06":[{"date":"2015-03-06","sign":"0"}]};`?

Thanks.

Comment: a date as key? but why?

Comment: @Blackbelt ya Its give me server side

Comment: @Blackbelt this is Current date which is able to fetch but I cant able to This kind of JSON Parsing data.

Comment: is 2015-03-06 is a constant value or this position will always have the current date

Comment: @PramodYadav Ya Exctaly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("2015-03-06");
```

instead of

```
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

because jsonArray's key is "2015-03-06" not "YYYY-MM-DD".Hope it will help.

Comment: I am also trying this kind of data but It Not convert into Valid Json Parsing which Provide in URL data = {"2015-03-06":[{"date":"2015-03-06","sign":"0"}]};

Answer (score 0):

if it is always correct date then you can parse it as below:-

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray(dateFormat.format(date).toString());
```

then get the values you want from this array,but i will still say having date as key in JSON response is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using "YYYY-MM-DD". Which is not going to return the current date. It is always "YYYY-MM-DD". So You are try to read json with the key name "YYYY-MM-DD". That is the reason you are getting the null pointer.

If this is the case then you can get Current date and time by using other functions For ex.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

And the next thing you can pass this date as your key.

ex.  `jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray(strDate);`