# Get JSON Response in Android for Weather?

Tags: android, json

I have develop the weather App and I want to use this URL,
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=11.11111&lon=22.2222

and get the information only, country,sunrise,sunset,temp_min,temp_max,name.
How get the response?

please suggest me.
Thanks.

```
{
        sys: {
            message: 1.3106,
            country: "IN",
            sunrise: 1426123283,
            sunset: 1426166271
        },

        main: {
            temp: 306.561,
            temp_min: 306.561,
            temp_max: 306.561,
            pressure: 1016.81,
            sea_level: 1026.98,
            grnd_level: 1016.81,
            humidity: 43
        },

        name: "Sarkhej",
    }
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I don't know this API, but if this is a response you're getting, can't you just retrieve the info you need from this json, and skip what you don't need?

Comment: I want to getting response for this url. how to getting the reponse?

Comment: This is the response. You need to parse it

Comment: @Devil ya Exactly. I want to fetch this value

Comment: So just start it with. Your first tag is `JSONObject`.

Comment: @Devil ok If you have demo then send me.

Comment: Check androidHive code for that. You can get from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject one = new JSONObject(json);

JSONObject sys = one.getJSONObject("sys");
String message = sys.getString("message");
String country = sys.getString("country");
String sunrise = sys.getString("sunrise");
String sunset = sys.getString("sunset");

JSONObject main = one.getJSONObject("main");
String temp = main.getString("temp");
String temp_min = main.getString("temp_min");
String temp_max = main.getString("temp_max");
String pressure = main.getString("pressure");
...

String name=one.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTTPClient to fetch data from url.

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=11.11111&lon=22.2222");
                try {
                  HttpResponse response= client.execute(post);
                  String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    // you can parse this json string and can use it
String country = new JsonObject(json).getJsonObject("sys").getString("country");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Don't forget to add **internet** permission in manifest.

Comment: @Thanks but I want to country value then how to fetch it?

Comment: String country = new JsonObject(json).getJsonObject("sys").getString("country");