# How to Read and Write JSON using json-simple library?

Tags: android, json

I want to read this JSON file in Android using json simple library.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    },
    {  
        "name":"Mark",
        "city":"Oslo",
        "cars":[  
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
        ],
        "job":"Doctor"
    }
]
```

Comment: What's the problem you have here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you,

```
  import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
  import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
      String s = "[{\"name\":\"John\",\"city\":\"Berlin\",\"cars\":[\"audi\",\"bmw\"],\"job\":\"Teacher\"},{\"name\":\"Mark\",\"city\":\"Oslo\",\"cars\":[\"VW\",\"Toyata\"],\"job\":\"Doctor\"}]";
      try{
         Object obj = parser.parse(s);
         JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
         for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
             JSONObject jsonObj=(JSONObject) array.get(i);
             System.out.println(jsonObj.get("name"));
             System.out.println(jsonObj.get("city")); 
             JSONArray cars=(JSONArray) jsonObj.get("cars");
             for(int j=0;j<cars.size();j++){
                 System.out.println(cars.get(j));
             }
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: how to use optString function in json.simple library, as it is available in JsonObject provided in android

Answer (score 0):

You could use GSON library by google found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

An example of using this library in your case would be having a class called "Person" with certain fields that match the JSON:

```
Public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String[] cars;
    private String job;
}
```

You go from JSON to object by doing this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person p = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Person.class);
```