# How to parse nested JSON Using Android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse URL to get JSON response and particular values from that response. I dont have a sample code. Please give me a simple solution.
Below I have posted my URL and Response. I want to GET "School", Name" and Result values.

```
http://sample.com/login/username/ <username> /password <password>?  

{
    "response":{
                "School":"SBOA",
                "Name":"Anitha",
                "Class":"Tenth",
              },
                "Result":"Good",
}
```

My Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String strJson="URL";
        String data = "";
        System.out.println(strJson);

        try {
            JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);

            //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("response");
            System.out.println(jsonRootObject);

            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //    int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                String name = jsonObject.optString("School").toString();
            //   float salary = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.optString("salary").toString());

             //   data += "Node"+i+" : \n id= "+ id +" \n Name= "+ name +" \n Salary= "+ salary +" \n ";*/
            }
            //output.setText(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not here for doing your home work. do by your self or search on _Google_ `how to parse JSON in Android`?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I have tried by using lots of sample code but. Nothing simple soltion. I am doing login activity. If I parse that URL, then once the URL got response, I need to go another activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read exactly that JSON, use this:

```
/** Verify that your strJson string contains this:
 * {
 *   "response":{
 *               "School":"SBOA",
 *               "Name":"Anitha",
 *               "Class":"Tenth",
 *             },
 *               "Result":"Good",
 * }
 */
String strJson = ??;
Log.d("TAG", "strJson: " + strJson);
try {
    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
    JSONObject response = jsonRootObject.getJsonObject("response");
    String schoolString = response.getString("School");
    String nameString = response.getString("Name");
    String classString = response.getString("Class");

    String result = jsonRootObject.getString("Result");
} catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Error reading json: " + jsonRootObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: Great Help! Thank you Buddy!

Comment: I am facing this error buddy : org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject..@Joakim

Comment: verify that the strJson String contains valid JSON. Your error indicates that it contains the string "http". Verify that you are actually downloading some JSON data and putting it in your strJson object

Comment: If you are unsure whether your String contains valid JSON, use for example http://jsonlint.com/ and paste the content there. My code snippet will only work if JSONLint says your text is valid Json.

Comment: I am passing JSON URL Buddy! Like "http://.....com/login/username/ <username> /password <password>?"

Comment: You have to download the JSON data from that Url before you parse it. The link itself doesn't contain the school, name, class information...

Comment: No. If I parse Username and password with my URL, Then JSON response will give school etc informations! Please help me buddy!

Comment: change the getString(xx) to start with the capital letter. response.getString("School"); instead of response.getString("school");

Comment: Now nothing error. but its not comming into try. Nothing values printed buddy!Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSONObject named json then follow this  for getting school value

```
try{
jsonRootObject .getJSONObject("response").getString("School");
}catch(JSONException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Warlock. I have posted my code Could you please look at. Its a good way of parse?

Comment: What are you trying to do actually, because your code not shows , how you get the JSON

Comment: I need to Parse Above I have mentioned sample URL with multiple (User name and Password)Parameters. Then if the URL gave correct response I need to go home activity. Its a Login process.