# Having trouble in retrieving json data. How to retrieve it

Tags: android, json, parsing

Basically i am trying to make an weather app. And i tried to retrieved some data (lets say lat and lon from crood object) but whenever i run the application it doesn't show me any  error but it show in logcat an exception which says "No value for crood". I have tried every resource that i had but i am unable to display data to textviews.

this is the json i want want to target

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":      [{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50d"},     {"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"},  {"id":311,"main":"Drizzle","description":"rain and drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":286.15,"pressure":1013,"humidity":87,"temp_min":286.15,"temp_max":286.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.1,"deg":200},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1445700000,"sys":  {"type":1,"id":5089,"message":0.0153,"country":"GB","sunrise":1445668823,"sunset":1445705286},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

This is how i am doing it

```
            String finalJson=buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONObject jsonObject =parentObject.getJSONObject("crood");
```

If somebody help me with this logic how to parse it. I want to get lat,lon,name,description,temp and pressure out of this data and i want to show it in textviews.

Comment: That should read as "coord" *not* "crood"

Comment: Your object says "coord" but you write "crood".

Comment: yes , using wrong key

Comment: Thank you x10. I am so dumb. I still need help. Help me with logic i want to target other objects too like temp pressure. how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems was with key. I was using wrong key. :3 crood instead of coord

Comment: Have you been watching Croods lately? :D

Comment: Haha yes seriously :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the Model, declare what u want in set and get.
2. Next create the arrayadapter and position your objects.
3. Create Activity declare the

   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

   ```
               HttpGet request = new HttpGet("Url Json Url");

               HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

               HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

               String json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

               JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(json);

               newsList = new ArrayList<NewsModel>();

               for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
   ```

   {

   ```
                   JSONObject row = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                   NewsModel data = new NewsModel();

                   data.setTitle(row.getString("title"));

                   data.setContent(row.getString("content"));

                   data.setExcerpt(row.getString("excerpt"));

                   data.setDate(row.getString("date"));

                   data.setImage(row.getString("feature_image"));

                   newsList.add(data);
   ```

Comment: I am having problem with modeling. I don't know how to make it. Yes i know but i am confused. If you can guide with modeling that would be much of help

Comment: can u share ur full data

Comment: first using jsonlint.com check the vaild json or ont.

Comment: Create the model In below that

Answer (score 0):

create model below that

```
ublic class NewsModel implements Serializable{

String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getExcerpt() {
    return excerpt;
}

public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
    this.excerpt = excerpt;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

String content;
String excerpt;
String date;
String image;
```

}