# How to access JSON response and display it in new activity in android?

Tags: php, android, json

I am getting the JSON response from PHP as {"success":'Hi Namrata...'} when the details are filled out in the editText field. I want to read the success value and display it in the new activity and in case of {"error":'something happened'} I want to be on the same activity.. How can I do that.
Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button blogin;TextView content;
public EditText uname, pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    content=   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.content );
    blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);

    blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new JsonTask().execute("https://www.aboutmyclinic.com/test.php",uname.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString());

        }
    });



}

public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("firstParam", params[1])
                    .appendQueryParameter("secondParam", params[2]);
                    //.appendQueryParameter("type", params[3]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


            connection.connect();



            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {

                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        content.setText(result);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://www.startingandroid.com/registration-and-login-with-back-end-php-and-mysql/

please check this. here you will find full detail about sending and receiving data to server and how to parse it as well.

Comment: Parse the response and  do it accordingly

Comment: Probably JSON String is `result ` then what problem u are getting in sending `result ` String using Intent to next Activity

Comment: parse JSON coming in response : link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this in your postexecute method

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
            String sucessvalue= json.getString("success");

          Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("sucessval",sucessvalue);
          startActivity(i);

        }
```

get in another activity

```
String valueofsucess = getIntent().getStringExtra("sucessval");
```

Comment: I want this success value on a new activity not on the same activity.

Comment: i am going on the new activity but I am not getting the success value.

Comment: have you put the second line on second activity

Comment: you have to put this line after setContentView in your second activity

Comment: I did the same. Still getting the same result.

Comment: can i see on team viewer

Comment: I added this in the second activity:    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(valueofsucess);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content1);
        layout.addView(textView);... NOw I am getting the success value on next page.. Thanks  a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change below line -

```
new JsonTask().execute.....
```

to

```
new JsonTask(MainActivity.this).execute
```

Inside the class JsonTask modify -

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context context;

    JsonTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
```

rest all same

Modify your onPostExecute() as below -

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        String result = "error";
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(s);
            if(jObj.has("success")){

                result = jObj.getString("success");
                startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class)
                .putExtra("result", result));
            }else{
                content.setText(result);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Namrata Singh: context = MainActivity.this that u passed to ur AsyncTask

Comment: It says "Unfortunately, MyApplication has been stopped".

Comment: @Namrata Singh: well u didn't passed the context to Asynck. I've edit my answer check it out I'm sure it'll help :)

Comment: @NamrataSingh: plz lets talk in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100739/how-to-access-json-response-and-display-it-in-new-activity-in-android

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to chat. I am new  here.

Comment: @Namrata Singh: where u stuck at?

Comment: Error is - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Namrata Singh: I've moved the String result declaration outside if block can u plz check it now.

Comment: @NamrataSingh can you please try retrofit tutorials for beginners

Comment: @NamrataSingh: on which line r u getting the error?

Comment: @NamrataSingh you webservice define is wrong it does not stands properly for JSON format please check with you service developer :D

Comment: @kevz  Now I'm getting a different error -                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.namrata.clinic/com.example.namrata.clinic.Login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @sector11   I'm not getting you and I'll try retrofit later.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are starting project right away can you start moving to some networking libraries. Like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Because it will help you for longer run in project.

```
    public class RetrofitActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<ResponseBody> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit);
            makeRequest("ashish", "ashish");
        }


        private void makeRequest(String userName, String password) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://www.aboutmyclinic.com/")
                    .build();
            Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);
            User user = new User(userName, password);
            Call<ResponseBody> loginRequest = service.login(user.getFirstParam(), user.getSecondParam());
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Logging in");
            dialog.show();
            loginRequest.enqueue(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.i("Response", "" + response);
 Log.i("Response", "" + response.body().toString());
        try {
            Log.i("Response", "" + response.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            dialog.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error", "Unexpected response");
            dialog.cancel();
        }

        public class User {
            String firstParam;
            String secondParam;

            public User(String userName, String password) {
                this.firstParam = userName;
                this.secondParam = password;
            }

            public String getFirstParam() {
                return firstParam;
            }

            public void setFirstParam(String firstParam) {
                this.firstParam = firstParam;
            }

            public String getSecondParam() {
                return secondParam;
            }

            public void setSecondParam(String secondParam) {
                this.secondParam = secondParam;
            }
        }
    }



    public interface Service {

        @POST("/test.php")
        public Call<ResponseBody> login(@Query("firstParam") String firstParam, @Query("secondParam")String secondParam);
    }
```