# Responce data as json array in Android

Tags: android, json

I am sending a `JSON` data to server and the server returning a data as `JSON`. How can I save the returning data as `JSONArray`? The returning value is in 'responce' variable, How can I save this response as `JSONArray`. I need to use the returning `JSONArray` to update my db.

This is my `JSON`,

```
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Sss",
    "dob": "10/1/2000",
    "gender": "Male",
    "mobile": "123456780",
    "address": "asdas"
}]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-objects)

Comment: Post some code for context. What are you using for making the request?

Comment: Can you please add the json format or a dummy json, which you are getting as response?

Comment: [{"_id":"1","name":"Sss","dob":"10\/1\/2000","gender":"Male","mobile":"1234567890","address":"asdasd"}]

Comment: JSONArray json = new JSONArray(responce);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(responce); //don't blame for typo of responce
```