# How to parse JSON with Volley?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I want to parse this [json (my)](http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC) with [tutorial (source code)](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley).

My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
        new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener <JSONArray> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating")).doubleValue());
                        movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                        // Genre is json array
                        JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                        ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                            genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                        }
                        movie.setGenre(genre);

                        // adding movie to movies array
                        movieList.add(movie);

                    } catch(JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        int i = 1;
        return true;
    }

}
```

This code is from androidhive but I don't know how to parse that json(my).

So, how to parse json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-objects)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String url = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Do you fancy stuff
                    // Example: String gifUrl = jo.getString("url");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Anything you want
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: You could save a parsing line by using `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest`  ;) 
Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Comment: Yep I know that :D

Comment: It's not giving any error but it also not showing json.my code is:

Comment: }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Anything you want
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);}

Comment: Can you hastebin/pastebin your activity code? Thanks