# count total row of json data using volley android studio

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an API that gives the following JSON data as a response.

```
{
"status": 200,
"error": false,
"user": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nama": "Jane Doe",
        "handphone": "081234567890",
        "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
        "nama_bisnis": "Permata Cell",
        "pekerjaan": "Wirausaha",
        "fb_id": "Jane Doe",
        "ig_id": "@jane_doe",
        "no_wa": "0812345678",
        "komentar": "",
        "user": "http://agenproduk.dianarthaselaras.com/user_img/1.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "nama": "Arifin",
        "handphone": "janedoe@gmail.com",
        "email": "081234567890",
        "nama_bisnis": "tripay",
        "pekerjaan": "pengusaha",
        "fb_id": "",
        "ig_id": "",
        "no_wa": "",
        "komentar": "",
        "user": ""
    }
]
}
```

How to find the size of the `user` array from the response & set it to a `textview`.
Any example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this link [how to parse json with volley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601290/6565331) you can find the code needed to parse Json and after parsing you can get rows count and assign it to textview like:

```
int count = jsonArray.length(); 
countTv.setText(Integer.toString(count))
```