# how to convert or read php object response to json?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, gson

i have get response like this

```
Array ( 
    [status] => 9 
    [message] => Your devices not verify! 
)
```

i use this code but not read response `Html.fromHtml(jsonString).toString()`

so,how can read this in android or json object format?

```
i also use
  GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonb.create();
            Post pst;

            pst = gson.fromJson(jsonString,  Post.class);

 Post.class
class Post
        {
            String message;
            String status;

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-objects-in-android)

Comment: no it is not duplicate

Comment: It was multiple times, look @IgorIlic answer.

Comment: Better try this way with `HttpURLConnection`.